# jQuery or Javascript helper to get a LatLng from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I need to let the user input a geocode (LatLng ) of an arbitrary point of the map, for store in the DB and later use.

Before embracing the duty, Do you know a jQuery plug-in or javascript that:

- Pop-ups a Google map
- The user navigate the map
- The user click on a point
- It places the selected LatLng in a textbox
- Close the pop-up

(or something along the lines)

Comment: what version of google maps are you using? I have an old version that's part of v2 that works fine. It doesn't use jquery, however.

Comment: @ScottE I think he's trying to do it with a jQuery rather than touching the Google Maps API.

Comment: @ScottE: v3 preferred (no key is nice), but maybe I can use part or migrate the script. Thanks!

Comment: @tgandrews: no problem dealing with the API, just lazy to do all the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use the v3 api since it is equally easy to use and fast to learn as a plugin.Also a plugin won't offer you the popup.

So here is my solution:

**1. Import**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

**2. Place a div in your html**
    `<div class="mapClass" id="mapDiv" ></div>`

**3. [Initialize your map](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)**

> var map;
>
> > var greece = new google.maps.LatLng(38.822590,24.653320);
> >
> > ```
> > //Map options
> > var mapOptions = {
> >     zoom: 6,
> >     center: greece,
> >     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
> > };
> > //Make a new map
> > map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),mapOptions);
> > ```

Voila,you get your map and the navigation controls

**4.[Bind  onclick event](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventListeners)**
    `google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click",yourFunction);`

**And implement your function to get the coords from the click and fill some textfields or      something plus [add a marker](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers)**

```
function getCoordinates(event){
  if (event.latLng) {
       var marker;
       //Fill your textfields
       document.getElementById('yourLngTextfield').value=event.latLng.lng();
       document.getElementById('yourLatTextfield').value=event.latLng.lat();

       //Remove any previously added marker and add a marker to that spot
       if(marker!=null){
            marker.setMap(null);
       }

       var latlng = event.latLng;
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng
             map: map
        });
  }
}
```

That's it.It is not tested though.

Now if you want to add all this in popup use [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

If you still want to use plugins check [here](http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/03/10-jquery-plugins-for-easier-google-map-installation/)

Cheers