# Google Maps API V3 : multiple markers and ajax infowindows? (best performance)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using the excellent [$GoMap jquery plugin](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/index.php) which is basically a wrapper for google maps API V3. It has served me well but when using lots of markers 60+ there seem to be some performance issues, so i've decided it's time to use the V3 API directly.

I've read a fair few beginners tutorials but considerring I'm after performance I'd like to get your thoughts/snippets the most efficient way of achieving the following  natively in the V3 API...(but for 60+ markers)

```
$(function() { 
    $("#map").goMap({ 
        maptype: 'ROADMAP',
        mapTypeControl: false, 
        zoom: 9,
        markers: [        {  
            latitude: 52.941364, 
            longitude: 0.648730,         
            html: { 
                content: '<img src="http://localhost/gv2010/user_area/assets/js/carousel/loader.gif"/>',
                ajax: 'http://localhost/gv2010/maptest/ajax/gmap_window.php?job_id=4002&img=40%2Fj4002_i2523&name=B%26b+With+Tlc&village=Brancaster&url_str=bandbwithtlc&rooms_num=&sleeps_text='
            } 
        },                {  
            latitude: 52.963097, 
            longitude: 0.742940,         
            html: { 
                content: '<img src="http://localhost/gv2010/user_area/assets/js/carousel/loader.gif"/>',
                ajax: 'http://localhost/gv2010/maptest/ajax/gmap_window.php?job_id=4003&img=40%2Fj4003_i2358&name=Scolt+Cottage&village=Burnham+Overy+Staithe&url_str=scoltcottage&rooms_num=&sleeps_text='
            } 
        },                {  
            latitude: 52.904720, 
            longitude: 0.623171,         
            html: { 
                content: '<img src="http://localhost/gv2010/user_area/assets/js/carousel/loader.gif"/>',
                ajax: 'http://localhost/gv2010/maptest/ajax/gmap_window.php?job_id=4200&img=42%2Fj4200_i4599&name=1+Ringers+Cottage&village=Docking&url_str=1-ringers-cottage&rooms_num=&sleeps_text='
            } 
        }
        ],
        icon: 'map_marker.png'        
    }); 
});
```

any help really appreciated

Comment: update: ok it turns out it was FireBug causing the performance issues, still really keen to translate this into native google maps if anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the [marker clusterer](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/)?Check [this speed test](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/speed_test_example.html) first.
Also please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618371/jquery-or-javascript-helper-to-get-a-latlng-from-google-maps/4623798#4623798) for some sample code of how you can use the google maps api directly.

Comment: yep, I've looked at a lot of clustering tools, however I'm not ready to start doing clustering until I've got what I currently have in native API V3. - the bit i'm not sure on is how to do the ajax info windows?

Comment: Well since you are using jquery first set the info window like in here http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows and in the click listener make an jquery ajax request and use jquery .html() to set the info window content